# Having problems creating a Renew action and view in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

please can somebody help me with this .i want to create a renew link which will update some of the fields in a table called members,am using rails 3 and i have created my action and the corresponding view but i still have an error that states

**"undefined method'renew_member_path' for #<#:0xb66bcae0>"**

below is the action i created in the members_controller

Class MembersController

```
def renew
  @member = Member.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @member.renew_attributes(params[:member])
      format.html { redirect_to(@member, :notice => 'Member was succesfully Renewed.'}
      format.xml  {head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => 'renew'} 
      format.xml { render :xml => @member.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity}
    end
  end
end
```

I created a view called renew.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Your route is not set. You need to update your routes.rb file to something like this:

```
match 'members/renew' => 'members#renew', :as => :renew_member
```

Comment: thnx for the help but i have added that and now its saying "Couldn't find Member with ID=renew" so i added :id/ to it to make it "match 'members/renew' => 'members#renew', :as => :renew_member" then it throw out this error too "undefined method 'renew_attributes for #<Member:0xb67e8400>"